# Utility.SearchPrincipals returns users as SecurityGroups

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, csom

When I call SearchPrincipals to search for a user name, I get back results with a `PrincipalType` of `SecurityGroup` instead of `User`. This is odd since the user should be a.... user.

What are the reasons why this could be happening?

```
Utility.SearchPrincipals(context, context.Web, "user name", PrincipalType.All, PrincipalSource.All, null, short.MaxValue);
```

This is an on-premise SharePoint 2013 environment.

Comment: Have you tried PrincipalType.user instead of all?

Comment: I haven't, but I'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify [principal type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.principaltype.aspx) for search

```
Utility.SearchPrincipals(context, context.Web, "user name", PrincipalType.User, PrincipalSource.All, null, short.MaxValue);
```

Comment: Tried specifying PrincipalType.User, but I get no results back.

Answer (score 0):

Still happening in other environments, years later...the answer seems to be to use `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ClientPickerQuery.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.ClientPeoplePickerResolveUser` and then `Web.EnsureUser` to make sure the user has been added to the site!